# Is it possible to train probabilistic model to return several distributions?

Tags: deep-learning, distribution, gaussian, probabilistic-programming, gaussian-process

I have nonlinear data of function y(x), which is let's say parabolic. At some points of **x** there are several y's (look at the picture).

[image]

Is it possible to train a probabilistic model to return several distributions (when needed) i.e. several means and variances. For example: when I feed **a (x=a)** to the model -> it returns 2 red distributions (2 means and 2 variances), and when I feed **b (x=b)** to the model -> it returns 1 blue distribution.

Thanks.

Comment: Interesting question! Can you flip x,y so that you have a proper function x(y).

Comment: For reference the function your trying to describe is a one to many function as in one x value gives many y values (if my a-level maths serves me correctly). It technically isn't a function as functions can't be one to many.

Answer (score 1):

That data can be modeled as a [statistical process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_process), where the distributions and parameters change as a function of x. This is in contrast to modeling it as a typical statistical distribution which assumes the same distribution and parameters throughout a range.

The "a" range could be modeled as a bimodal distribution and the "b" range could be modeled as a unimodal distribution.

Answer (score 1):

The conditional distribution of $Y$ when $X=a$ is bimodal. The mean is in the middle, and reporting it as such is correct (the mean of $1,2,3,91,92,93$ is indeed $47$).

This will be reflected somewhat in the variance being extremely wide. If you want to model a full distribution, you could consider quantile regression at many quantiles. I found [this article](https://towardsdatascience.com/deep-quantile-regression-c85481548b5a) on neural networks to predict multiple quantiles.

Such a quantile regression approach would, correctly, show that the conditional median is in the middle of the parabola, but then you’ll have a big jump to the, say, 45th and 55th percentiles before the quantiles bunch up around each mode.